# Java converting a group of string to String Array Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class sourc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = null;
        Integer id = null;
        String strings = "one*10*two*11*three*12";
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(strings, "*");
        while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
            name = st2.nextElement().toString();
            id = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextElement().toString());
            String[] str = new String[]{name};
            List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
            System.out.println(al);
            ArrayList<Integer> arrli = new ArrayList<Integer>(id);
            arrli.add(id);
            System.out.println(arrli);
        }

}
```

i have output like

[one]

[10]

[two]

[11]

[three]

[12]

But i need output like

[one,two,three]

[10,11,12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strings = "one*10*two*11*three*12";
    String[] spl = strings.split("\\*");//split with *
    ArrayList<Integer> arrli = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : spl) {//loop throw your resutl
        if (s.matches("\\d+")) {//check if your input is int or not
            arrli.add(Integer.parseInt(s));//if int add it to list of ints
        } else {
            al.add(s);//else add it to list of Strings
        }
    }
    System.out.println(al);//output [10, 11, 12]
    System.out.println(arrli);//output [one, two, three]

}
```

---

This will help you in case you have two successive `ints` or `String` like this :

```
"one*9*10*two*11*three*four*12"
//--^---^---------^------^
```

---

**EDIT**

> now am having my input like
>   **"astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj"** i need to split
>   string and numeric separately

In this case you have to use Patterns for example :

```
String str = "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    strings.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(nums);
System.out.println(strings);
```

**Outputs**

```
[12, 124, 1234, 123, 1234]
[astv, atthh, ggh, dhr, sfff, dgdfg, mnaoj]
```

Comment: thanks YCF_L, now am having my input like "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj" i need to split string and numeric separately

Comment: why you using matcher here

Comment: because there are no clear pattern your string is mix with numbers, so it is difficult to extract numbers and strings with the first solution, the better choice is to use Patterns @ManojKumarGovindharaj

Comment: now i tried to split the value like [12124, 1234123, 1234] and [astv, atthhggh, dhrsfff, dgdfg, mnaoj] i tried along with pattern but output doesn't spotted

Comment: what did you mean, @ManojKumarGovindharaj ?

Comment: now my input is like  "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj" the output must be [12124,1234123,1234] [astv,atthhggh,dhrsfff,dgdfg,mnaoj

Comment: i already edit my answer lassst time did you try to test it @ManojKumarGovindharaj ?

Comment: now my input is like "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj" the output must be [12124,1234123,1234] [astv,atthhggh,dhrsfff,dgdfg,mnaoj]

Comment: actually i want to replace comma( , ) instead of ( * ) and split the value like [12124,1234123,1234] [astv,atthhggh,dhrsfff,dgdfg,mnaoj] @YCF_L

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143974/discussion-between-ycf-l-and-manoj-kumar-govindharaj).

Comment: @ManojKumarGovindharaj create a new question instead this is not good to edit your question every time, let it clean so others can understand moren and like i said create a new question describe every thing so we can help you i'm waiting your new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask good luck

Comment: am in chat @YCF_L

Comment: sorry @ManojKumarGovindharaj i cant use char, it is blocked in my network !

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a tokenizer here, rather you can just split the string using `String#split()` with some regex replacement logic.

```
String input = "one*10*two*11*three*12";
String[] words = input.replaceAll("\\d+\\*?", "")
                      .split("\\*");
String[] nums = input.replaceAll("[^0-9*]+\\*?", "")
                     .split("\\*");
```

Comment: I like the answer

Comment: @AndyTurner Get with the program, Java is going functional.  If your entire program takes up more than 3 lines then it's worthless :-)

Comment: Frankly, I would really dislike reading something like this in production code, just for the purpose of splitting a string by a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

You should create two `List`s outside the loop, and add the elements to them inside the loop:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
    names.add(st2.nextElement().toString());
    ids.add(Integer.parseInt(st2.nextElement().toString()));
}
System.out.println(names);
System.out.println(ids);
```

Note that this code makes assumptions on the input (even numbers of elements, where the second element of each pair is an integer), and will fail if the input doesn't match these assumptions.

Comment: hi Eran now i have a situation my input like "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj" what i want to update

Answer (score 1):

Why not use split?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String strings = "one*10*two*11*three*12";


    final String[] split = strings.split("\\*");

    final List<String> resultStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> resultInt = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            resultInt.add(split[i]);
        } else {
            resultStrings.add(split[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(resultInt);
    System.out.println(resultStrings);
}
```

Comment: thanks Alexey if i an input like "astv*12atthh124ggh*dhr1234sfff123*dgdfg1234*mnaoj" how i want to split it... i want an output like [astv,atthhggh,dhrsffff,dgdfg,mnaoj] [12,124,1234,123,1234]